# Scale seems incorrect in QGIS 3.4.3 for Mac in the editing window

Tags: qgis-3, mac

I've been working on a map for a few months now and decided to export it in Composer to see how it's rendering out elements like creek labels when I noticed the exported scale was vastly different than my working scale. I checked to make sure that I'm using the same projection for both the project and composer. I decided to open it up in QGIS 2.18 and the scale looked to be the same as in the composer.

So it seems that the editing window in 3.4.3 for Mac may be off. I'm almost wondering if it has to do with the retina update for QGIS. It seems like it's basically double the scale (i.e. 1:50,000 looks like 1:100,000) Does anyone else see this issue or is there something that I'm missing?

I'm currently using QGIS 3.4.3 on OSX 10.14.2. Couple of images below to show what I'm talking about. (Top from editor window and bottom from composer export.)

[image: Image from editing window]

[image: Image from composer window]

Comment: What scale did you set the map canvas in the composer to? How big is the canvas?

Comment: Canvas is 42"x30" and the map is set to the same scale as the map in the editor, 1:145000. My thinking is that it has something to do with the retina display update as the Composer appears to be rendering correctly when compared to previous versions of QGIS.

Comment: I'd rather say it's about your map canvas (print composer) being about twice as large as your monitor/map window ("working area"). Though usually this difference leads a larger scale of the basemap in the canvas instead of a smaller one.

Comment: It seems to be a scaling issue and not a magnification issue due to the size changes of the fonts to the shapes. My composer is set to no magnification and identical scales. I'm hoping to hear from anyone who has a retina display with the latest version of QGIS to see if they have the same behavior to determine if it's a bug or an improper configuration.